# How do I use apparel?

Tags: eve-online

As part of the recent gift giving in EVE Online, I have a t shirt that I can apparently use on my character;

[image]

The only problem is, it's not obvious *how* I use it? Currently this item appears in my hangar and regardless of the amount of clicking I do on the item it never seems to appear on my character.

What am I doing wrong? How do I use apparel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Captain's Quarters in a station, and use the Character Customization Mirror. Here you will be able to apply apparel items that you've acquired.

Answer (score 3):

The item appearing in the hangar is simply so you can trade or sell it. In order to use it, you need to go to the character customisation screen while docked by clicking on the "Re-Customization" button on the "Station Services" panel;

[image]

The item will then appear under the appropriate category for the item (in this instance, it's a t shirt, so it appears under "Top");

[image]

After you commit your changes on the "Re-Customization" screen, the item in your hangar will disappear. If you change what you're wearing in the future, and remove the t shirt, the item will reappear in your inventory so that you can later sell it if you don't want it anymore.